# Run nohup with multiple command-line arguments and redirect stdin

Tags: python, linux, daemon, nohup

I want to run

```
python argument1.txt argument2.txt >logfile.log
```

with nohup, but I get no output because it is redirecting the input to null.
I want it to accept command line arguments at first and do work in nohup way.

```
nohup python argument1.txt argument2.txt >logfile.log
```

when I run the above command i get the following output.
    nohup: ignoring input and appending ...
which means areguments are being ignored. on the manual it says i have to do some input redirection, which i dont know how to.

Comment: You mention redirecting standard input in the title, but make no further mention of it in the question.  What is the problem?  You should be able to run: `nohup python argument1.txt argument2.txt <input.file > logfile.log 2>&1` and there shouldn't be any noise from `nohup` (and no `nohup.out` file) and standard input should come from the named file and both standard output and standard error should go to the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nohup redirects to nohup.out

If you wish to get the nohup look and feel and redirect to another file(s) do this:

```
( python argument1.txt argument2.txt >logfile.log 2>logfile.err & ) &
```

This doesn't hang up when you log out. (you can redirect stderr to the same log file by replacing `2>logfile.err` for `2>&1`

Comment: (1) `nohup` does not redirect to `nohup.out` when neither stdout nor stderr is going to the terminal. (2) `nohup` does arrange to ignore the HUP signal before it runs the program.  To fix (2) you'd need to add `trap '' HUP;` before the `python` command.  But it is not necessary to do this at all.  And you've not covered standard input, which the question title mentions but the body does not.

Comment: when I run the above command i get the following output.
    nohup: ignoring input and appending ...
which means areguments are being ignored. on the manual it says i have to do some input redirection, which i dont know how to.